# Django Template Remainder Error

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api

I am using Django to and Google Calendar's API to process some user data. So I have some code here copied from one of the examples on the quickstart guide. (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/pythondef

```
def index(request):

credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
eventsResult = service.events().list(
    calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
    orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

#Commented out the below parts because I want to pass these variables into the index.html page
#if not events:
#   print('No upcoming events found.')
#for event in events:
#    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
#    print(start, event['summary'])

return render(request, 'calendarfunction/index.html', {'events': events}))
```

From my understanding, I am passing a dictionary called events to the index.html file and in my html file I can do something like this:

```
{% for event in events %}
    <div>{{ event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date')) }}</div>

{% endfor %}
```

But I get a syntax error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '% event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date')) %' from '% event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date')) %'
```

Comment: No, you can't do operations like that in the Django template language. And `{{% %}}` isn't the right syntax for tags anyway. You should probably go and do the Django tutorial.

Comment: Oops sorry, I made a mistake in writing it. It is supposed to be {{}}